# Qt release version crash

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

My project works in debug version, but always crashes in release version, immediately after start. I am using clion and MINGW64 for windows. Even the following code crashes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QByteArray>

int main() {
    QByteArray a("");
    return 0;
}
```

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui)
```

Comment: Do you have more info about the crash, e.g. a Windows error code? Not that your release binary simply fails to locate the Qt DLLs to run properly... Concerning this, you may research for [windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). No experience with MinGW but for Qt5 in VS2017 (native Windows appl.) it worked fine on my side.

Comment: error code is 0xC0000139. I run windeployqt with my release build exe and it somehow detects it as debug executable. Maybe something wrong with clion configuration?

Comment: _I run windeployqt with my release build exe and it somehow detects it as debug executable._ That makes me wondering. There are the command line arguments `--debug` and `--release` described in the link I provided above. Did you call `windeployqt --release`?

Comment: I reinstalled Qt and MinGW. And windeployqt now detects it as release automatically and fixes the problem. thanks